# javascript | search in object

Tags: javascript, object, key, key-value

I have an object:

```
var obj = {7:[57,58], 8:[37]}
```

I'm looking for the function that return true or false if key/value exist in object.

For example:

```
function check(key, value) { //  7,58

   return true;
}
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tou can do this:

```
var obj = {7:[57,58], 8:[37]}

function check(key, val) {
    return !!obj[key]&&!!~obj[key].indexOf(val);
}

check(7, 58); // true
check(7, 57); // true
check(8, 9); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function check(obj, key, value) {
    return (obj[key]) ? (obj[key].indexOf(value) != -1) : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
function check (key, value) {

  //  Grab the object keys and iterate over them using `some`
  return Object.keys(obj).some(function (el) {

      // make sure you convert `el` to an integer before checking
      // it against the key
      return parseInt(el, 10) === key && obj[el].indexOf(value) > -1;
   });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/rzvm0810/1/)